# Blackberry check permission for facebook integration

Tags: java, facebook, web-services, blackberry

In my application I am using Facebook integration but not able to find how many checks / permissions I should use. I just wrote some code but am not able to find all media permissions and "addpermission" or "Application Permission"

```
private void checkPermissions()
{
    ApplicationPermissionsManager apm = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance();
    ApplicationPermissions original = apm.getApplicationPermissions();

    if ((original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_MEDIA) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_LOCATION_DATA) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_RECORDING) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_DEVICE_SETTINGS) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_CROSS_APPLICATION_COMMUNICATION) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SERVER_NETWORK) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) &&
        (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_EMAIL) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW)) 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use these different types of permissions in your Application which can solve your problem

```
  ApplicationPermissions permRequest = new ApplicationPermissions();
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_MEDIA);
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_LOCATION_DATA);
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_RECORDING);
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION);
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_DEVICE_SETTINGS);
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_CROSS_APPLICATION_COMMUNICATION);

  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET);
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SERVER_NETWORK);
  permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_EMAIL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
String APPLICATION_ID = "xxxxxxxx";
String APPLICATION_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxx";
String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;

ApplicationSettings as = null;
Facebook fb = null;
```

And in constructor get the instances like below:

```
    as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
    fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
```

Now this fb object you can use as you need.

And i have also integrate like above. Never used the permissions you mentioned in the questions. Hope those are not required.

Thanks.